# Sun GRID Engine - submit jobs that  'prefer the powerful' machine instead weaker machines

Tags: gridengine

We have 10 windows machines under sun grid(single CPU/4G RAM). Except name, every thing else is same on all these machines. Now we added two new machines to same grid. These two have 16 CPU , 48G RAM.

I would to to instruct Sun GRID Engine that 'prefer the powerful' machine. If these (new boxes) machines heavily loaded only then use the other machines. How can i do this?

Commands are submitted via normal `qsub -l [attribute list]  [script.sh]`

(attribute list is "windows=1,group=it", in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. change in scheduler config (`qconf -msconf`) the queue_sort_method from the default `load` to `seqno`
2. update in the queue definition (`qconf -mq queue`) the seq_no with a default value that is valid for all nodes and a lower value for the powerful nodes

With this config the powerful nodes will be chosen first if they have slots available.

Comment: does it mean the jobs will ignore the "load" altogether? What happens if the powermachine is heavily loaded and weak machine is free?

Comment: Read `man sched_conf` for details about that. But basically the way it works is that you can assign the same seq_no to multiple machines. In that case the load is used as a secondary sort method.